# Windows server 2019

Tags: internet-connection, windows-server-2019

I had to download windows server 2019 for my studies in MSSQL DATABASE ADMINISTRATION and when it was done installing and my laptop restarted, it shows that I am not connected to the internet and is also not giving me any options to connect to the internet which is now slowing my studies as I cannot do anything... can someone please help?

Comment: You have overwritten your working Windows environment with Windows Server? If that's the case, you will need another working Windows computer to return to your previous version (which is what?).

Comment: Why not try and install the network drivers?

Comment: Why didn’t you just install MySQL on your original Windows installation? It sounds like you replaced a licensed copy of Windows with an unlicensed copy of Windows Server

Comment: If you have the image of the original drive, restore it, and see if you can run Server 2019 in a VM.